# Jquery Cloning div contents a variable number of times

Tags: php, jquery

Jquery:

```
$('#partsOrderQty').blur(function(){

var rowCounter = $(this).val();

console.log(rowCounter);

var toAddRow = $("#skidListings").children().clone();

for (var i=0; i<rowCounter; i++) {

    $("#skidListings").append(toAddRow);

    console.log("Ran Once Just Now");

}

});
```

html:

```
<div id="skidListings">

        <input class="ConfirmQty" name="ConfirmQty" type="text" value="<?php echo $confirm;?>"/>

        <input class="ConfirmDesc" name="ConfirmDesc" type="text" value="<?php echo $des[$final]; ?>"/>

        <input class="ConfirmWeight" name="ConfirmWeight" type="text" value="<?php echo $ShipWeight[$final]*$confirm; ?>" />

        <input class="ConfirmClass" name="ConfirmClass" type="text" value="<?php echo $class[$final]; ?>"/>

        <input class="ConfirmNMFC" name="ConfirmNMFC" type="text"  value="<?php echo $NMFC[$final]; ?>"/>

        <input class="ConfirmLength" name="ConfirmLength" type="text" value="<?php echo $length[$final]; ?>"/>

        <input class="ConfirmWidth" name="ConfirmWidth" type="text" value="<?php echo $width[$final]; ?>" />

        <input class="ConfirmHeight" name="ConfirmHeight" type="text" value="<?php echo $height[$final]; ?>" /><br />   

    </div>
```

Why is this only cloning once even though it prints the console message the correct amount of times?  Do I have to clear the values?  The function is to allow me to manually specify a different number of pieces than what is pulled from our database.  I understand that I cannot clone things with ID's but I selected for the children, none of which have id's.  I need to keep the classes in, should I remove the names?   Does that matter?

Edit: as per request http://jsfiddle.net/NxSwA/

Comment: Just curious if you realize and care that both your code and the answer will duplicate all the content? So if you have 1 in toAddRow the first time... you'll get 2... but if you add 1 again, you'll get 4, then 8, etc.

Comment: To be honest, I don't expect my users to change it more than once (I only have two expected users), but I've been burned by not making these things idiot-proof before, so I will take care to change it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the code to

```
var toAddRow = $("#skidListings").children();
for (var i=0; i<rowCounter; i++) {
  $("#skidListings").append(toAddRow.clone());
  console.log("Ran Once Just Now");
}
```

this should work

Update #1: Reson for that is the following from the .append documentation: *"If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)"* (thanks to @Felix King in the comments below)

Comment: I take it that the clone is destroyed each use.  Thanks a bunch, this works!!

Comment: @roasted, if you enter 5 it will only add 1.

Comment: @Andy: From the `.append` documentation: *"If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)"*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for... one problem (atleast I saw it as a problem) is that if I add 2, I'll get 3 (as expected), but now if I add 1 I should expect to have 4 right? Instead I would end up with 6 because it is cloning the entire contents of `#skidListings`

I'd wrap each skidListing in a `div class=skidListing`, and then just replicate one instance of them... the last probably, it would look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NxSwA/1/

```
$('#partsOrderQty').blur(function () {
    var rowCounter = $(this).val();
    console.log(rowCounter);
    var toAddRow = $("#skidListings").children(".skidListing").last();
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCounter; i++) {
        $("#skidListings").append(toAddRow.clone());
        console.log("Ran Once Just Now");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="partsOrderQty" />
<div id="skidListings">
    <div class="skidListing">
        <input class="ConfirmQty" name="ConfirmQty" type="text" value="<?php echo $confirm;?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmDesc" name="ConfirmDesc" type="text" value="<?php echo $des[$final]; ?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmWeight" name="ConfirmWeight" type="text" value="<?php echo $ShipWeight[$final]*$confirm; ?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmClass" name="ConfirmClass" type="text" value="<?php echo $class[$final]; ?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmNMFC" name="ConfirmNMFC" type="text" value="<?php echo $NMFC[$final]; ?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmLength" name="ConfirmLength" type="text" value="<?php echo $length[$final]; ?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmWidth" name="ConfirmWidth" type="text" value="<?php echo $width[$final]; ?>" />
        <input class="ConfirmHeight" name="ConfirmHeight" type="text" value="<?php echo $height[$final]; ?>" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice with this... if I add 2 I'll have 3... if I add another 1, I'll have 4 (not 6). This would also allow you to have more control over each `skidListing` as far as CSS, gathering data in JS, deleting some, etc.

Comment: Can I just define the variable outside of the blur function to have it remain constant?

Comment: Come to think of it, it's a skid count, the way it's worded, it will be the total number of lines.  I need to either change the wording or add a check for matches of this class.

Comment: Now to figure out how to remove lines, thus continuing my trend of causing problems by solving others.  I guess maybe one day I'll be a pro, and will foresee these kinds of things.

Comment: If you use the above code, you could remove a line pretty easily... you could remove the last line like `$(".skidListing").last().remove();` or a certain one with `$(".skidListing").eq(3).remove();`... or by reference if you have events bound to them or something in relation to them.